# How to properly send Etag back to web server in HTTP If-None-Match request header?

Tags: http, caching, http-headers, etag, request-headers

I'm trying to use caching correctly using HTTP Last-Modified and Etag headers. From what I can see, web servers send back an Etag with one of 3 formats:

- A standard Etag, e.g. `wAUL9rDkgMueFoa7ZLPa/Vjx3ak`
- A standard Etag in double-quotes, e.g. `"a8ef0-5b8e443cf07ba-gzip"`
- A weak Etag, e.g. `W/"17ba-WxSGP4eaXoBk6hGG35IOD+5mrwQ"`

When I send a new HTTP request for the same URL, I can send a header `If-None-Match: <cached etag>` which will cause the server to send a 304 request if it hasn't changed.

Should I remove the quotes from an Etag and send that, in order to match properly? For instance, if a standard Etag is `"a8ef0-5b8e443cf07ba-gzip"`, should I send `If-None-Match: "a8ef0-5b8e443cf07ba-gzip"` or `If-None-Match: a8ef0-5b8e443cf07ba-gzip`?

Similarly, with a weak Etag should I remove the `W/` at the beginning and also the quotes, so that if the weak etag is `W/"17ba-WxSGP4eaXoBk6hGG35IOD+5mrwQ"`, I send a header of `If-None-Match: 17ba-WxSGP4eaXoBk6hGG35IOD+5mrwQ`?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for `ETag`, `If-None-Match`, and other headers related to conditional requests is defined in [RFC 7232](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7232#appendix-C).

As can be seen there, a valid `ETag` requires double quotes:

```
ETag = entity-tag
entity-tag = [ weak ] opaque-tag
opaque-tag = DQUOTE *etagc DQUOTE
```

So the first example you mentioned is invalid.

`If-None-Match` should just be a comma-separated series of `entity-tags` (or `*`), including the double quotes and any weak indicators. The standard includes a [few examples](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7232#section-3.2):

```
If-None-Match: "xyzzy"
If-None-Match: W/"xyzzy"
If-None-Match: "xyzzy", "r2d2xxxx", "c3piozzzz"
If-None-Match: W/"xyzzy", W/"r2d2xxxx", W/"c3piozzzz"
If-None-Match: *
```

So: send the `ETag` back the same way you received it.